# How to visually identify a Qt widget held in a variable in code?

Tags: python, qt, widget

I'm working on a project maintained by many people, and I'd like to quickly identify a Qt widget I see in code.

One way I can see to do that, is to hide it (`widget.hide()`), and see which one has disappeared in the GUI. This is not very practical, for many reasons (window has to be reopened, change can be hard to spot if the GUI is complex, ...).

Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Someone on my team told me about [GammaRay](https://doc.qt.io/GammaRay/). Seems very interesting, just maybe a bit complex to jump into right now. I'll definitely check it again later though, it seems really helpful with debugging Qt projects!

Comment: Just realized, my question also applies to layouts, would be cool to find a way to quickly identify them!

Comment: GammaRay is a really great tool, but yes it is complex.

Comment: Change the background color instead of hiding it?